# Adjusting different opacities for the joined line and filling color in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I am currently using the ListPlot command in Mathematica to create a plot of some data. My goal is to adjust the opacity of the joined dashed line and the filling color differently, but I'm having trouble achieving the desired effect. Unfortunately, I have failed to modify the opacity of the filling color without affecting the dashed boundary. This has made it difficult to clearly see the boundary. I'm wondering if there's any way to increase the opacity of the joined dashed line without altering the opacity of the filling color (in the attached image it is 0.1). Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
F = {{1, 3}, {2, 7}, {3, 2}};
G = {{1, 4}, {2.1, 3}, {2.9, 3}};
ListLogPlot[{F, G}, Filling -> Bottom, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> { {Lighter[Green, 0.1]     , Dashing[0.03], 
    Thickness[0.02], Opacity[0.1]}, {Lighter[Red, 0.01]     , 
    Dashing[0.03], Thickness[0.01], Opacity[0.1]}}(*,
 FillingStyle\[Rule]{{Directive[Opacity[0.9],Blue]},{Directive[\
Opacity[0.1],Yellow]}}*)
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListLogPlot[{F, G}
 , PlotStyle -> {
   {Opacity[0.9, Darker@Darker@Green], Dashing[0.03], Thickness[0.005]}
   , {Opacity[0.9, Darker@Red], Dashing[0.02], Thickness[0.002]}
   }
 , Filling -> {
   {1 -> {Bottom, Directive[Opacity[0.1, Lighter[Green]]]}}
   , {2 -> {Bottom, Directive[Opacity[0.1, Lighter[Red]]]}}
   }
 , Joined -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PoreyS I am glad I was able to do so. Thanks for the accept.